# ArgumentOutOfRange Exception in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I'm trying to access column name of the selected row in DataGridView control in windows form, but I'm getting **ArgumenOutOfRange** exception of the following code:

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.SelectedColumns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].ToString());
```

Producing:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

Could anyone please tell me how can I overcome from this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataGridView.SelectedColumns collection is a separate collection from the DataGridView.Columns and can have a different set (a subset) of the columns.

For example if you have a 5 column view, and the third and the fourth are selected, then

```
DataGridView.SelectedColumns.Count == 2
DataGridView.Columns.Count == 5
```

and of you are using the fourth column (index of 3) your code becomes

```
DataGridView.SelectedColumns[3]
```

which blows up (rightly) with a IndexOutOfBounds.

To sum it up, in your case, you should be using the Columns property, and not the SelectedColumns.

Answer (score 4):

`SelectedColumns` is a list that only contains the selected columns (yeah, that's how it works). So this list size is different from the size of the `Columns` property list (which is what you want, obviously).

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, then probably you should be getting column value from a `Columns` collection and not from `SelectedColumns` collection.

```
dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`ColumnIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.columnindex.aspx) property can return -1 (from the documentation):

> The index of the column that contains
>   the cell; -1 if the cell is not
>   contained within a column.

Could this be the case for you?